# C++/CLI: Cannot explicitly implement interface member with different return type

Tags: interface, c++-cli, explicit

Let's say we have two C++/CLI interfaces declaring Foo() members with different return type.

```
public interface class InterfaceA
{
    bool Foo();
};

public interface class InterfaceB
{
    int Foo();
};
```

What we want to do here is to have a class that instantiates an object that can be accessed through the above interfaces. So, the straight forward way to do that would be:

```
public ref class Class : InterfaceA, InterfaceB
{
    virtual bool Foo() = InterfaceA::Foo { return true; }
    virtual int Foo() = InterfaceB::Foo { return 10; }
};
```

Unfortunately that gives us compiler error "overloaded function differs only by return type from". Is there any workaround for this C++/CLI limitation?

Comment: In one word No, this is a design issue and not C++\CLI or any other language

Comment: Well, c# allows me to have two methods of same name with different return values explicitly implemented in a single class. So i wouldn't say it is not c++/cli related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have to rename the method.  For example:

```
public ref class Class : InterfaceA, InterfaceB
{
public:
    virtual bool Foo() { return true; }
    virtual int Foo2() = InterfaceB::Foo { return 10; }
};
```

Note how this is never a real problem.  If code has a reference to Class instead of the interface for some reason then it can always call InterfaceB::Foo() with a cast:

```
Class^ obj = gcnew Class;
safe_cast<InterfaceB^>(obj)->Foo();
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy ) Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: thanks again for giving me the right answer. I am advancing pretty fast now with my code conversion from c# into c++/cli. Except i stuck again with another issue that is related to interface event explicit implementation. Probably you could help me again, i'd really appreciate it. Please take a look: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15404891/c-cli-interface-event-explicit-implementation)